# How to remove repeating substring in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to remove repeating string in pandas, but the method did not work.

### My attempt

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(['haha','lollol','hi'])
ser.str.replace(r'(\w)\1',r'\1',regex=True) # does not work

But this works:
re.sub(r'(\w+)\1',r'\1', 'haha') # gives ha
```

How to remove the repeated string in each words in pandas series?

Comment: This isn't unique to pandas Series, right? You could probably change your question to just removing repeated substrings.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile My data is already in pandas dataframe, I would like to do some string manipulation. Obviously I can do re.sub for-loop but am looking for more generic pandaic way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ser.str.replace(r'(\w+)\1',r'\1',regex=True)
```

output:

```
0     ha
1    lol
2     hi
```

Comment: Oh!! I forgot the mighty PLUS  + sign, thanks a lot. This was bothering me for many minutes.